# NSAttributedString inserting a bullet point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsattributedstring, bulletedlist

So I have an `NSAttributedString` I want to insert a `bullet point` at the beginning of a portion of text. How can I do this? How do I create a `CTPAragraphStyle` that creates this bullet point when I display the text?

**Edit:**
Should be available on **iOS**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easy bit: [mutableAttributedString insertAttributedString: @"•\t" atIndex:0];

The hard bit. Something along the following lines. (This is extracted from a bigger project, but it may give you a decent start.)

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"•\texample bullet fill out the text to check what happens on the second line and make sure it is lining up OK"];

CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTLeftTextAlignment;
CGFloat paragraphSpacing = 0.0;
CGFloat paragraphSpacingBefore = 0.0;
CGFloat firstLineHeadIndent = 15.0;
CGFloat headIndent = 30.0;

CGFloat firstTabStop = 15.0; // width of your indent
CGFloat lineSpacing = 0.45;

CTTextTabRef tabArray[] = { CTTextTabCreate(0, firstTabStop, NULL) };

CFArrayRef tabStops = CFArrayCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**) tabArray, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks );
CFRelease(tabArray[0]);

CTParagraphStyleSetting altSettings[] = 
{
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &lineSpacing},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent, sizeof(CGFloat), &firstLineHeadIndent},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierHeadIndent, sizeof(CGFloat), &headIndent},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierTabStops, sizeof(CFArrayRef), &tabStops},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &paragraphSpacing},
    { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacingBefore, sizeof(CGFloat), &paragraphSpacingBefore}
}; 

CTParagraphStyleRef style;
style = CTParagraphStyleCreate( altSettings, sizeof(altSettings) / sizeof(CTParagraphStyleSetting) );

if ( style == NULL )
{
    NSLog(@"*** Unable To Create CTParagraphStyle in apply paragraph formatting" );
    return;
}

[string addAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSObject*)style,(NSString*) kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil] range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];

CFRelease(tabStops);
CFRelease(style);
```

You need to include the CoreText framework and then import CoreText/CoreText.h

Comment: This is the go-to example for setting up a paragraph style in iOS, but I would caution against releasing `tabStops` and `style` until the attributed string which uses them is released. In my project, I had to propertize all the owned style components to keep from getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 43):

Here's a more modern approach that works from iOS6:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"•\texample bullet fill out the text to check what happens on the second line and make sure it is lining up OK"];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle;
paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraphStyle setTabStops:@[[[NSTextTab alloc] initWithTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft location:15 options:nil]]];
[paragraphStyle setDefaultTabInterval:15];
[paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:0];
[paragraphStyle setHeadIndent:15];

[string addAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle} range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much. Confirmed working on iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 40):

Here is nice solution with Swift

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 280, height: 600)
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
label.numberOfLines = 0

let arrayString = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
]

label.attributedText = add(stringList: arrayString, font: label.font, bullet: "")

self.view.addSubview(label)
```

#### Add bullet attributes

Swift 4.2++

```
func add(stringList: [String],
         font: UIFont,
         bullet: String = "\u{2022}",
         indentation: CGFloat = 20,
         lineSpacing: CGFloat = 2,
         paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = 12,
         textColor: UIColor = .gray,
         bulletColor: UIColor = .green) -> NSAttributedString {

    let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor]
    let bulletAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: bulletColor]

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    let nonOptions = [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]()
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
        NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: nonOptions)]
    paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
    //paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
    //paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20
    //paragraphStyle.tailIndent = 1
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation

    let bulletList = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for string in stringList {
        let formattedString = "\(bullet)\t\(string)\n"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            textAttributes,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
        let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bullet)
        attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttributes, range: rangeForBullet)
        bulletList.append(attributedString)
    }

    return bulletList
}
```

Swift 4.0 & 4.1

```
func add(stringList: [String],
         font: UIFont,
         bullet: String = "\u{2022}",
         indentation: CGFloat = 20,
         lineSpacing: CGFloat = 2,
         paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = 12,
         textColor: UIColor = .gray,
         bulletColor: UIColor = .green) -> NSAttributedString {

    let textAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor]
    let bulletAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: bulletColor]

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    let nonOptions = [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]()
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
        NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: nonOptions)]
    paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
    //paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
    //paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20
    //paragraphStyle.tailIndent = 1
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation

    let bulletList = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for string in stringList {
        let formattedString = "\(bullet)\t\(string)\n"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            textAttributes,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
        let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bullet)
        attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttributes, range: rangeForBullet)
        bulletList.append(attributedString)
    }

    return bulletList
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: Such a nice answer, but if string contains new line("\n"), indent are broken. How can I handle this situation

Answer (score 5):

You don't implement a bulleted list with a paragraph style in iOS. Set your tab stops as you'd like, and then insert a tab, bullet, tab at the beginning of the paragraph.

`CTParagraphStyle` is quite inflexible, so you can't just add new styles of your choosing to it. You can, however, add any attribute you like (`MYBulletStyle`) to arbitrary runs within the `NSAttributedString`. This can be useful for passing the bullet-list information around with the `NSAttributedString` and then rebuilding the string to include the bullets when you're ready to display it. But Core Text won't render the bullets for you automatically.

Comment: I know this post is pretty old, But you mind giving some sample? how would a tab stop solve the problem, when you want the whole paragraph to be indented except the bullet?

Comment: I know this question is pretty old but.... set paragraph indent and tab stop to the same value . BUT you set the first line paragraph indentation to none. Then the first line begins with bullet and tab. The result is the the first line of text, after the bullet, starts in line with the rest.

Answer (score 5):

Here is Krunal's excellent answer in **Objective-C**. It also removes the paragraph spacing on the last bullet item to avoid the extra bottom padding on the UILabel.

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.frame = CGRectMake(40, 100, 280, 600);
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
label.numberOfLines = 0;

NSArray *stringArray = @[@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                         @"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
                         @"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
                         @"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                         ];

label.attributedText = [self attributedStringForBulletTexts:stringArray
                                                   withFont:label.font
                                               bulletString:@""
                                                indentation:20
                                                lineSpacing:2
                                           paragraphSpacing:12
                                                  textColor:UIColor.grayColor
                                                bulletColor:UIColor.greenColor];
```

And here is the function which creates the actual attributed text:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForBulletTexts:(NSArray *)stringList
                                              withFont:(UIFont *)font
                                          bulletString:(NSString *)bullet
                                           indentation:(CGFloat)indentation
                                           lineSpacing:(CGFloat)lineSpacing
                                      paragraphSpacing:(CGFloat)paragraphSpacing
                                             textColor:(UIColor *)textColor
                                           bulletColor:(UIColor *)bulletColor {

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor};
    NSDictionary *bulletAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: bulletColor};

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = @[[[NSTextTab alloc] initWithTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft location:indentation options:@{}]];
    paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation;
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing;
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation;

    NSMutableAttributedString *bulletList = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    for (NSString *string in stringList) {
        NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t%@\n", bullet, string];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedString];
        if ([string isEqualToString: stringList.lastObject]) {
            paragraphStyle = [paragraphStyle mutableCopy];
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 0;
        }
        [attributedString addAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
        [attributedString addAttributes:textAttributes range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];

        NSRange rangeForBullet = [formattedString rangeOfString:bullet];
        [attributedString addAttributes:bulletAttributes range:rangeForBullet];
        [bulletList appendAttributedString:attributedString];
    }

    return bulletList;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the actual answer for this question but this can help.

just add " • "

Even i was looking for something like this for my textView. What i did, just append above string with my string and pass it to my textView, same can be done for labels also. I answered this for future Viewer.

Comment: Hmm I'm wondering if that resizes properly as you increase the font or not

Comment: ya. It will increase the size because it just an alphabet. upvote if you think this is a cool way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Another riff on @krunal's answer, this time slightly simplified as an NSAttributedString initializer in Swift 5:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init(stringList: [String], bullet: String = "\u{2022}", indentation: CGFloat = .zero, lineSpacing: CGFloat = .zero, paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = .zero) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let tabStopOptions: [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any] = [:]
        
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
            NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: tabStopOptions)
        ]
        
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation
        
        let bulletList = NSMutableAttributedString()
        for string in stringList {
            let formattedString = "\(bullet)\t\(string)\n"
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)
            let attributedStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
            attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle], range: attributedStringRange)
            
            bulletList.append(attributedString)
        }
        
        self.init(attributedString: bulletList)
    }
}
```