# Adding colored bullets to text inside textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am having a textview which contains text and list of some items.I want to display text in black color and bullets in orange color. How to do that.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can't do this

Comment: `NSAttributedString` with • character?

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.1

```
  let  DelevieryDateString = "●" + "This is a list item!"

    let DelevieryDateStr: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: DelevieryDateString)

    DelevieryDateStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    value: UIColor.green, //color code what you want
                                    range: NSRange(
                                        location:0, // Find the location of the bullet and replace it
                                        length: 1))
lblitem.attributedText = DelevieryDateStr
```

Answer (score 0):

Using " • " should work for you.
Check [**UILabel with bullet points**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533851/is-it-possible-to-format-uilabel-with-bullet-points) and [**Bullet list in UITextView**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685221/bullet-list-and-numbered-list-in-uitextview).
For combining text with bullet list you should use [**NSAttributedString**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/). [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644501/objective-c-nsattributedstring-inserting-a-bullet-point) is an example you will be interested in.

Comment: Thank you Nitish for your answer . I have added bullet but I want to change the color of that bullet to orange . how could I do that I can't understand.\

Comment: @Tejasvi : Welcome. Please accept the answer if it is the solution. It shall be a reference for others in future.

Comment: @Tejasvi : Did you try NSAttributedString ?