# How to display hollow bullets using unicode in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unicode, bullet

I am developing an app which have an list. Which show bullets in this format:

[image]

I googled but nothing found. I only found this `\u2022` which shows bullets like this:

[image]

I their any way from which I can achieve my desired output.

One alternate solution is to use `UIImage` or `UIView`. but I don't want to use this way.

Comment: Try NSMutableAttributedString:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/25803376/988169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of those: `\u07cb`, `\u09e6`, `\u0a66`. Those are Unicode compliant. I don't think you have to do anything complex like image views and so on.