# How to change imageview constraint according to label text using storyboard in swift

Tags: swift, storyboard, constraints

How to give constraint to below view

[design img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltsya.png)

Here how to give constraints to blue doted imageView.

**for label** giving

```
 top = 10, leading = 20, trailing = 20
```

so if text change label height also changing... but the doted image stick on the same place

because for blue doted image

```
width = height = 15, leading, top to above doted image = 20
```

When text change in label.. Label is expending but the doted image not coming with its label.

How to give constraints to small doted image.. if the above label increases its height then doted image also come down similar to its right label, Please suggest me constraints.

Comment: Why not using NSAttributedString and its bullet points? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644501/nsattributedstring-inserting-a-bullet-point etc.

Comment: @Larme, i am looking for using storyboard constraints

Comment: You can do that with UIStackView without any constrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you must have to give 1st lable's bottom constraint with 2nd dotted image view (I mean vertical spacing between 1st lable and 2nd dotted image view)

[image: vertical spacing between 1st lable and 2nd dotted image view]

**Final result**

[image: Final result]

[image: New image with 1st label constaint]

Comment: i am not getting, whats the constraints for label

Comment: i have given dotted imageview top to label bottom vertical spacing..still not getting

Comment: okay.Let me share detailed image of constraint

Comment: @iosswift New image is added and please make sure that lable's number of line is 0 and for multi line we must have to give all side constraint so please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can give constraints as follows:

**Image Constraints**

- leading 10
- Trailing w.r.t label 10
- vertically center w.r.t label
- height and width 20

[image]

**Label Constraints**

- Top 100 (modify the value as per your design)
- trailing 10

[image]

**Final Output:**

[image]

This will resolve your issue.