# How to display html lists in IOS UITextField?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I see an entry here:

[How to add bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533851/how-to-add-bullet-points-to-uilabel)

It shows how to add bullets into IOS UITextField.

What I need is something different. I want to save the HTML code in the database like:

```
<ul>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

And then show it in IOS application as seen in the browser.

What is the good way of it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any such HTML interpreter/parser that will directly convert this code to `NSString`.

What I would suggest is that : Save the text in database as plane string with bullets or any prefix as `<bullet>item1`.

And while showing to the UI, first read that string from the database and replace `<bullet>` with some text as  **•** (dot buttlet, Unicode code point `U+2022`).

Or you need to use regex to convert your HTML tag and then replace `<li>` with `•`

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  Why not just UIWebView instead of UITextField?

Comment: Agreed.  Then you wouldn't be relegated to just bullets.