# How can i start this remain text underneath it's upper text in UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to show remain text of line underneath it's upper line in UILabel. How can i do that? I used UILabel for to show this text and i set **Lines** = 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 cell.Describtionlabel.text = "Intelligient Keyboard Engine (IKE™) \n\t- When typing up IKE will give you suggestions and ideas. \nDictate \n\t- We also have audio mode which allows you to dictate your report and we type it up for you.\nSelf Transcribe\n\t- If you wish to type up yourself just select self transcribe as your delivery option."
```

[image]

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46891740/7084910

Comment: Thanks JD this link worked for me.

Comment: Happy coding...!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for the alignment, set label alignment to left,
2. Check if there is any initial space when you are setting the text to your label.If yes, remove that.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: I Don't want to align text to left side. if you see **Intelligient Keyboard Engine (IKE™)** is Header and **"When typing up IKE will give you suggestions and ideas."** it's Description. So i want Description to start with tab and so it's remain text as you can see in image is **"and ideas"** which should start below this text **"-When typing up..." **.

Comment: Label always start from the left alignment, if you need some starting space, i suggest you to instead of initial space, you can adjust the description label's leading constraint

Comment: Thanks @Madhur But what i needed is **NSMutableParagraphStyle**.

Answer (score 1):

User Swift Multiline String Literals

From the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID286)

> Multiline String Literals
>
> If you need a string that spans several lines, use a multiline string literal—a sequence of characters surrounded by three double quotation marks:

```
let quotation = """
The White Rabbit put on his spectacles.  "Where shall I begin,
please your Majesty?" he asked.
 
"Begin at the beginning," the King said gravely, "and go on
till you come to the end; then stop."
"""
```

[image]

Comment: I know this String Literals. But Don't know why i almost forgot this awesome feature. I already got my answer. Still thanks for help. :)